# Right shape of validation rules (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

I use these rules in my model:

```
 validates_presence_of :email, :message => "E-mail must be filled!"
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/, :message => "This is not email address!"
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message => "This email is already taken!"

  validates_confirmation_of :password, :message => "Password must be the same!"
  validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 40 }, :message => "Your password must have at least 6 characters!"
```

If I send an empty form, so as the output will be displayed all of those 5 lines above. What I have to do to display only the 1st and 5th rules?

Comment: did you try clear unused errors before rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's one solution](http://www.railway.at/2012/01/25/multiple-validations-on-one-field/).

Essentially the advice is to use the `:allow_blank` option on all validations except the presence validations. This makes Rails skip the validations if the field is blank. That way, you only see the error messages related to missing values when submitting an empty form.